# Convergence in measure involving $L^2$ convergence

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Question: Prove or disprove the following statement.
Let $f_k, f, h$ be measurable functions defined on $\mathbb{R}^n$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. If $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f_j - f|^2 |h|\, dx \to 0$, then there exists a subsequence $\{f_{j_k}\} \subset \{f_j\}$ so that $f_{j_k} h \to f h$ a.e in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

My attempt: Since $\Vert f_j |h|^{1/2} - f |h|^{1/2}\Vert_{L^2} \to 0$ as $j \to \infty$ then $f_j |h|^{1/2} to f |h|^{1/2}$ in measure so there exists a subsequence $f_{j_k} |h|^{1/2} \to f |h|^{1/2}$ a.e. Therefore, we have a subsequence $f_{j_k} |h| \to f |h|$ a.e. and necessary we have $f_{j_k} h \to f h$ a.e.